# Same z-index acting differently in different sites

Tags: css, z-index

I am seeing an error which I think is because of z-index, the error is really strange. See these two posts in two different sites (while keeping in mind that the data is same only the sites are having different css)

```
1st site (buggy one) : http://bloghutsbeta.blogspot.com/2012/03/testing-3.html

2nd site (the okay one) : http://www.bloghuts.com/2011/08/wizard-fashion.html
```

To see the error please go to first site then click on PLAY and while keeping it open, kindly go to the 2nd on and then click on PLAY you will see the error that I am talking about, I am not able to understand what's going on?

Comment: Include the relevant code in your question. This means: Stand-alone demos which demonstrate your problem. The reason for this request: The linked page could change, causing this question to be useless for future visitors.

Comment: what codes you want, css or both css and html? please make me clear ^^

Comment: It would be best if you gave only enough code to reproduce the problem. You can use jsfiddle.net to help you figure out what code that is. (Bonus: Figuring out how much code you can remove while still retaining your issue is a great way to debug, too!)

Comment: Well actually I added the code while I was editing and I realized that code for both of them is same except for the template design, Now do you think that I can add a whole template to js fiddle? its not issue with how I am posting the game, I have mentioned earlier both of them are using same css and html except that they are on different templates

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the issue is not because of z-index as they both are same for both sites, it must be something else that is effecting it. My guess is that the buggy site's design is maybe messing with it as I see contents appearing inside the game and when you click on borders the game disappears.

Answer (score 1):

Well I think I found out the issue I am not sure as I used firebug, my friend the problem is because of the values of z-index that you gave to #postarea #sidebar #sidebar1 #sidebar2 etc they have z-index:1 if you turn off them using firebug, it completely resolves the issue you are facing. I think z-index:1 is being considered bigger than z-index:99999999 that's why your content appear above the game and creates issues for you.

Comment: I tried what you said using firebug, it do solves the issue. Can you tell me why is z-index 1 larger in value than 9999999999?